# Java for intermediate .NET Developer

Tags: java, .net

I am a .NET Developer with about 5 years of web development experience using Microsoft technologies starting with classic ASP to ASP .NET 3.5.

I do have a little background in Java as well and can write/understand Java code very easily. I am looking for resources (online, books) that are compatible with my .NET experience. I am only interested in web development in Java and want to start at intermediate level even if it may require me to look up some details.

What path or resources would you recommend for intermediate .NET web developers to gain equivalent proficiency in Java web development tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Get an IDE: IntelliJ (my preference), Eclipse, Netbeans;
- Get an application server: Glassfish (my preference; either v2 or v3 Prelude), JBoss or, if you're feeling adventurous, SpringSource dm server;
- Get a JDK eg 6u11;
- Get a copy of Spring 2.5.6 (or 3.0M2 if you're feeling adventurous);
- Get a copy of the Spring reference documentation;

Put the pieces together.

Comment: +1 for IntelliJ (using 8 yet?); servlet container like Tomcat 5/6 or Jetty is sufficient if you steer clear of EJBs and stick with Spring and POJOs.

Answer (score 4):

Get yourself a copy of eclipse, and just start reading other people's code, and reading some java docs. The Java website has all the docs online, and they're one of the best language specs I've seen.

Really, if you know C# pretty well, Java should be a cake walk. The languages are pretty similar, so you just need to get to know the different frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most helpful book in regards to learning Java's web development framework, Java Server Faces:

[Core JSF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131463055)
- Great examples and explainations throughout on the whole process of using the JSF Framework.

And of course for anyone new to Java I would recommend:

[Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)
- Covers various design patterns and practices.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience that official Java exams are better than the .Net equivalents, so it may be worth starting there?

Answer (score 0):

Search for a servlet/JSP tutorial (Good, albeit a little old, example [here](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/)). 
You'll get basic knowledge of Java web application development.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your level is, [JSF for Nonbelievers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf1/) is the best introduction to JSP/JSF.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out [Bitter Java](http://www.manning.com/tate/).

It's a book that shows you the wrong way to do things, why it's wrong, and then it shows you the right way.

It pretty much falls in line with the evolution of the j2ee framework. Started with servlets, then moved into jsps, then command pattern, etc.